# App crashes on segue from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `UITableViewcontroller` (TVC) embedded in a navigation controller. That TVC has two static cells, each corresponding to a new `UITableViewController`. I'm simply dragging from the cells to the next view controllers and naming the segues. Not using any segue code.

The segue from the TVC to the first `UITableViewController` works perfectly. The segue from the TVC to the second one crashes upon selecting the row. It never makes the segue. The two child table view controllers are nearly identical, and I've checked every storyboard setting to make sure they're the same.

Is this something I need to be handling in code? If so, why?

EDIT: I'm getting `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<App.FromFBViewController 0x12650bdb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'` 
and `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.`

Comment: You have to post error you get, from this we don't know much...

Comment: I added an exception breakpoint but don't get an error in the debugger. Just get `(lldb)` and the thread breakpoint highlights the `class AppDelegate` declaration

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a TableViewController with each cell having segue going to a different screen.  The problem turned out to be that the TableViewController would only call one segue which worked fine for the cell it corresponded to but not for any of the others.

I ended up switching to a number of buttons that looked like cells attached to a scrollview.

Comment: I don't want to do that because I feel like there should be a workaround. Doesn't seem complicated enough to have to do that.

Comment: I think the workaround might be that you programmatically call the segue from inside the controller with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueForRow1" sender:self];` when you determine which row was called instead of using the storyboard method of dragging segues to the next controller from the cell.

Comment: I did that and it still didn't work. I'm using `if indexPath.row == 0 { self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: self) }` in Swift

Comment: Is the segue1 line dragged from the cell, or from the top part of the controller?

Comment: From the view controller's yellow icon

Comment: Darn, sorry I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I got it. Had some stuff that wasn't hooked up properly

Comment: Please add an answer and accept it so that this question isn't unanswered